# How to set the "Mark Completed" flag in Exchange 2007 w/SP2

Tags: outlook, set, exchange-server

Does anyone know how to programmatically set the "Mark Complete" flag in Exchange 2007 which makes a check mark appear in outlook. In outlook you can right click and select the "Mark Complete" option. I want to achieve this programmatically based on some conditions. Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can create an Add-In in Visual studio for Office Outlook & can achieve the same functionality.

Comment: What API and programming language are you using?

Comment: So the add-in will update the flag in exchange?

Comment: ews 1.2, language c#, exchange box is running exchange 2007

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the ExtendedPropertyDefinition class:

//PidTagFlagCompleteTime

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd_PidTagFlagCompleteTime = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1091, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime);


msg.SetExtendedProperty(epd_PidTagFlagCompleteTime, DateAndTime.Now);
```

Comment: it set the property but when I go look in outlook at that particular message it doesn't show the check mark for "mark complete" by the message

Comment: Ok I got it. Here was the solution.               ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd_PidTagFlagStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);  and used em.SetExtendedProperty(epd_PidTagFlagStatus, 0x00000001); to change its status. Thanks Carlos for the pointing me to the extendedProperties.

Comment: Even though I set the PidTagFlagComepleteTime the message "Follow up. Completed on xxxxxxx" does not show. If I manually right click in outlook and select mark complete this shows. Is there some flag i'm missing.